# FCM Send message in PHP : JSON format?

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a clickable push message through PHP with FCM. Sending a notification with an image, a title and a body works but it doesn't work for links.

I'm using PHP & cURL to send a JSON to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
The function I'm using is one found here.

```
function sendnotification($to, $title, $message, $img = "", $datapayload = "")
{
    $msg = urlencode($message);
    $data = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'sound' => "default",
        'msg'=>$msg,
        'data'=>$datapayload,
        'body'=>$message,
        'color' => "#FF33CC"
        'link' => "https://www.mylink.com"
        );

    if($img)
        {
            $data["image"] = $img;
            $data["style"] = "picture";
            $data["picture"] = $img;
        }
        
    $fields = array(
        'to'=>$to,
        'notification'=>$data,
        "priority" => "high",
        "link"=>"https://www.mylink.com"
        );
    

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key= MYKEY',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
            

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $result;
}
```

With this, I get the notification with the right picture, the right text but when I click on it, the notification doesn't lead me to the specified link.

The documentation mentions a totally different format for the JSON:

```
{
  "message": {
"token": "eEz-Q2sG8nQ:APA91bHJQRT0JJ...",
"notification": {
  "title": "Background Message Title",
  "body": "Background message body"
},
"webpush": {
  "fcm_options": {
    "link": "https://dummypage.com"
  }
}
```

}
}

I have tried using this type of JSON but when I do, I don't get any notification, I don't even get a respons from my cURL call.

My service working is also pretty standard:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-messaging-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-analytics-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
messagingSenderId: "xxx",
apiKey: "xxx",
projectId: "xxx",
appId: "1:xxx:web:xxx",
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('Handling background message ', payload);

 return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, {
  body: payload.data.body,
  icon: payload.data.icon,
  tag: payload.data.tag,
  data: payload.data.link,
});
  });

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
event.notification.close();
event.waitUntil(self.clients.openWindow(event.notification.data));
 });
```

I have also tried to replace data: by link: but it doesn't help.

I get the following error message in Chrome (not in Firefox) : Uncaught TypeError: messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler is not a function

I ready here it was because I use "notification" in the JSON but I have not found a working alternative.

Which JSON format should I use to make my notifications clickable?

thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: @anchoress no I ended up doing this differently (also with Firebase)

Comment: @Laurent in a service worker? how did you do it?

Comment: @FirefighterBlu3 the service worker I'm using is here : https://www.laurentwillen.be/firebase-messaging-sw.js